# Possible to use Jquery in a Js widget to be inserted on other sites

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I want to provide a widget on my website that other people can insert on their webpages, via :

Can I import and use Jquery in that file so that the user doesn't need to add it manually to his page.

How would I do this? (I'm new to Javascript too)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a simple copy and paste (i.e. copy the code in the jQuery file into your own JavaScript file).

If you wanted to keep the files separate, however, you could add the jQuery script to the DOM as follows:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "path/to/jQuery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Steve

Comment: thanks steve for your fast response. can I also ask:
- is this bad practice?
- if they have already got jquery loaded, will this cause a conflict? and should i check first and how?
- do I have to do anything to prevent it conflicting with other libraries they may have loaded?

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about the first; for the second, see http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great post on that topic: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/